# iPhone X safeAreaInsets Dynamic from function

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, ios11, safearealayoutguide

I'm using SnapKit for layout in my iOS project and in landscape mode i want to add some constraints at the bottom.

with the following code everything works good.

```
        containerView.snp.updateConstraints { (update) in
            update.left.equalToSuperview().offset(58)
            update.top.equalToSuperview().offset(0)
                if #available(iOS 11.0, *), UIDevice.isIphoneX {
                    let bottomPadding = self.viewController?.view.safeAreaInsets.bottom
                    update.bottom.equalToSuperview().offset(-bottomPadding!)
                }
        }
```

although i would like to make it more dynamic from a function something like this

```
func safeAreaEdge(_ view: UIView, _ edgePad: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *), UIDevice.isIphoneX {
        let padding = view.safeAreaInsets.edgePad
        return padding
    } else {
        return CGFloat(0.0)
    }
}
```

So i can get the padding like this  `safeAreaEdge(view, bottom)`

But i get an error

```
Value of type 'UIEdgeInsets' has no member 'edgePad'
```

Why I know that i have only those options `top,bottom,right,left` from `safeAreaInsets`
But is there any efficient way to make it dynamic ?